# how to use api.getSelectedNodes()

Tags: angularjs

I am working on angularjs grid options. I need to get the nodes and data of selected rows in the grid. Can anyone suggest how to use `api.getSelectedNodes()`/`api.getSelectedRows()` here to get the details. I am trying to get the data on a button click.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  enableSelection: true,
  rowSelection: 'multiple',
  rowMultiSelectWithClick: true,
  columnDefs: [],
  onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
    $scope.grid1Api = gridApi;
  },
};
$scope.onclick = function() {
  console.log("into click function");
  // tried various options. 
  // I am getting error "Cannot read property 'getSelectedNodes' of undefined"
  $scope.count = $scope.gridOptions.api.getSelectedNodes().length;
  console.log(count);
}
```

Comment: There isn't a `$scope.gridOptions.api` object. Shouldn't it be `$scope.api.getSelectedNodes()` or `api.getSelectedNodes()`?

Comment: Hi, I resolved this by replacing api with grid1Api(which has my gridApi object) "$scope.count=$scope.grid1Api.selection.getSelectedRows();"